# node.js adding new routes having cannot read property

Tags: express

I'm pretty new to Node, so please bear with me if this is really stupid. I'm just trying to add my own routes for a couple of new pages, which are built on a sample app I got from a book. Here are some code of my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    models = require('./models'),
    dbUrl = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://@localhost:27017/blog',
    db = mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {safe: true}),
```

and here are all the routes definition:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/studentLogin', routes.user.studentLogin);
app.post('/studentLogin', routes.user.checkID);
app.get('/studentLoginAfter', routes.tutorRequestForm.selectCourse);
app.get('/login', routes.user.login);
app.post('/login', routes.user.authenticate);
app.get('/logout', routes.user.logout);
app.get('/admin', authorize, routes.article.admin);
app.get('/post', authorize, routes.article.post);
app.post('/post', authorize, routes.article.postArticle);
app.get('/articles/:slug', routes.article.show);
```

The studentLoginAfter route is the one I'm trying to add, but every time I added it, I got an error like this:

```
app.get('/studentLoginAfter', routes.tutorRequestForm.selectCourse);
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectCourse' of undefined.
```

But in my tutorRequestForm.js file, I apparently defined my handler like this:

```
exports.selectCourse = function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('selectCourseForm');
};
```

Is there anything I missed? I thought it's should be very straightforward for adding new routes in this way, but I'm really frustrated at this point. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you missed to include your tutorRequestForm.js file. I would recommend you to read a good node.js tutorial and also one for express.js. For me, apparently it seems like you didn't get the real concept behind node and in particular express.js.

Nevertheless, you should do something like this:

```
// All the requires are here...
var tutorRequestForm = require('pathToTheFile/tutorRequestForm');
// All the routes are defined here...
app.get('/studentLoginAfter', tutorRequestForm.selectCourse);
```

This should then work for you. You've basically forgotten to include your file. Furthermore you are trying to access your function via the routes variable, which actually reflects another file.

Comment: thanks for answering, really appreciate it. I forgot to mention that I've put the tutorRequestForm.js under the routes folder, so it's indeed included. I've figured it out, it totally has nothing to do with the routing issue, turned out to be the page I'm randomly rendering for the routes requires some objects to be passed... At least, that's what I figured out... So, I re-redirecting the route to a new empty page, everything is fine now. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: All right, cool that it's working now for you! My pleasure to help you